# How to remove all toggle except for one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created html page which has got rollover png and thing that I want to do is when I clicked (make rollover) all png it has to be grayscale (I did it this part) and after that if I clicked any png other png must be default

If you check demo link you gonna understand.

[my codepen demo link](http://goo.gl/ahF5uE)

[and the link that I want to do (rating section)](http://goo.gl/r5Lsf5)

**My Codes**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function(e) {
          var el = $(this).attr("name");
          switch(el){
              case 'd1': $(this).toggleClass('d1_pasif'); break;
              case 'd2': $(this).toggleClass('d2_pasif'); break;
              case 'd3': $(this).toggleClass('d3_pasif'); break;
              case 'd4': $(this).toggleClass('d4_pasif'); break;
              case 'd5': $(this).toggleClass('d5_pasif'); break;
          }
    });
});
```

```css
.d-groups input[type="button"]{
  cursor:pointer;  
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d1 {

  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1.png);

}
.d1_pasif {
    background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1_pasif.png);
}
.d2 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d2.png);
}
.d2_pasif { 
background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d2_pasif.png);
}
.d3 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d3.png);
}
.d3_pasif {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d3_pasif.png);
}
.d4 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d4.png);
}
.d4_pasif {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d4_pasif.png);
}
.d5 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d5.png);
}
.d5_pasif {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d5_pasif.png);
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//anitur.streamprovider.net/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js?v=1.2" ></script>
        <div class="form-elements d-groups" style="padding:4px 0;padding-left:5px;margin:0 auto;display:block;">
            <input type="button" name="d5" class="d5"  />
            <input type="button" name="d4" class="d4" />
            <input type="button" name="d3" class="d3"  />
            <input type="button" name="d2" class="d2" />
            <input type="button" name="d1" class="d1" />

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `*_pasif` class from all others elements if clicked element has the `*_pasif` class like following.

```
$(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function (e) {
    var el = $(this).attr("name");

    if (!$(this).hasClass(el + '_pasif')) {
        $(".form-elements input[type='button']").not(this).each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass($(this).attr("name") + '_pasif');
        })
    }

    $(this).toggleClass(el + '_pasif');
});
```

**Update**

```
var buttons = $(".form-elements input[type='button']");
buttons.on("click", function (e) {
    var el = $(this).attr("name");

    var length = buttons.length,
        count = 0;
    buttons.each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass(this.name + '_pasif'))
            count++;
    });

    if (length == count) {
        buttons.not(this).each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass(this.name + '_pasif')
        });
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass(el + '_pasif');
    }
});
```

#### [CODE PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGqNey?editors=1010)

Comment: yes but I can choose more than one when I clicked my png and  if I choose all png  whenever click I ones it must be grayscale and other ones must be default png (sorry about my english)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function(e) {
      var el = $(this).attr("name");
      $(".form-elements input[type='button']").removeClass(); // Add this
      switch(el){
          case 'd1': $(this).toggleClass('d1_pasif'); break;
          case 'd2': $(this).toggleClass('d2_pasif'); break;
          case 'd3': $(this).toggleClass('d3_pasif'); break;
          case 'd4': $(this).toggleClass('d4_pasif'); break;
          case 'd5': $(this).toggleClass('d5_pasif'); break;
      }
});

});
```

Try this!

More compact version of above code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function(e) {
          var el = $(this).attr("name");
          $(".form-elements input[type='button']").removeClass(); // Add this
          $(this).addClass(el+"_pasif");
    });

    });
```

Both will work for sure.

Comment: Doesn't match the functionality at all of the shown site

Answer (score 1):

I've fully duplicated it [here](http://codepen.io/jy14898/pen/MKLyoN?editors=1111)

I basically made it so they all use the same .enabledclass, to simplify the code. I also then check if they are all ticked, and if so toggle them all when another is ticked (like the site does)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-elements input[type='button']").toggleClass('enabled');

  $(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(this).parent().children(':not(.enabled)').length == 0) {
      $(".form-elements input[type='button']").toggleClass('enabled');
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('enabled');
  });
});
```

Comment: how to do reverse ? it is something like that I want

Comment: This is how it works on the site? What do you mean by reverse?

Comment: I mean like trivago if u click demo link that I shared below you gonna see (rating area)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function(e) {
      var el = $(this).attr("name");

      if (!$('.pasif').length)
      {
        $('.d1').toggleClass('d1_pasif');
        $('.d2').toggleClass('d2_pasif');
        $('.d3').toggleClass('d3_pasif');
        $('.d4').toggleClass('d4_pasif');
        $('.d5').toggleClass('d5_pasif');
      }        
      $(this).toggleClass('pasif'); 
      switch(el){
          case 'd1': $(this).toggleClass('d1_pasif'); break;
          case 'd2': $(this).toggleClass('d2_pasif'); break;
          case 'd3': $(this).toggleClass('d3_pasif'); break;
          case 'd4': $(this).toggleClass('d4_pasif'); break;
          case 'd5': $(this).toggleClass('d5_pasif'); break;
      }
});

});
```

However this code is a bit messy, as you have to many unnecessary classes there. 2 classes should be enough to reach your goal.

Comment: Hi thank you so much my english is not enough to explain my issues sorry that is why [if u clik demo link](http://goo.gl/r5Lsf5) you gonna see rating section on the left.it must to be like this but logically I couldn't do that